# Mobile Browser can not view Azure Website

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I had done the following in the Azure portal:

1) I created a Resource Group, say, ABCResourceGp

2) I create a web app in Azure, ie: DrinkTest

3) joined a Subscription plan (Min) in order to use Domain Name

4) Buy a domain Name thru azure, say Drink.com

4.1) Add hostname for this Domain name

5) in My ABCResourceGP, I have

5.1) say, www(icon)  Drink.com     AppService Domain 
5.2) say, DNS(icon)  Drink.com     DNS Zone 
5.3) DrinkTest               App Service

When I use the Browser, I can see the Drink.com

Problem:
- when I use Mobile Browser in iPhone, I type either www.drink.com or drink.com, I don't see the website.

Comment: Do you get a message? Is the mobile device connected to WiFi or does it have its own connection? Does it use a proxy? My first idea would be that it's a DNS issue. You could [check DNS propagation](https://www.whatsmydns.net/) to determine if that's the issue.

Comment: @rickvdbosch,I really need help on what else I need to do on Azure since I have followed all the steps! How to solve this issue? I check on domain-status.com, I see my domainName is there. Why Mobile Browser cannot browser but deskTop browser can?? My Safari mobile browser can browse other websites but not mine.

Comment: @rickvdbosch, say , I type  drink.com  (this is used as illustration), I will get a webPage says: Hey, App service developers! But I did the same on Mobile Browser in iphone but I dont get any message ! What I need to do?  I have not deploy any Asp.netCore app to my web App in Azure yet.Thanks

Comment: You haven't answerd _any_ of the questions I asked... :/
I still think it's a DNS issue, because resolving the address should work exactly the same for desktop and mobile.

Comment: @rickvdbosch, my iphone is either connect to wifi or Mobile Network. I dont know what steps to take to resolve the DNS issue. Can you share with me how to go about it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@MilkBottle one thing you can try is access your mobile site directly by going to (drink).azurewebsites.net and the site should resolve on the mobile device (assuming everything is default - no code or just a basic ASP.net project). Assuming it does resolve, then like @rickvdbosch suggested, enter your DNS site name at https://www.whatsmydns.net/ and it should return the IP address that's under the Custom Domain blade of your app service. If it doesn't, then you know you have a DNS issue.